# How can I remove the overflow for the mobile version and center the cards?

Tags: html, css, mobile, overflow

I tried so much but I can't fix the overflow and just center the flipcards. I also have a url to the [dummy website](https://fp30.nl/paketten.html)

Can someone please help me? I don't know what to do

```
        <!-- flip-card-container -->
        <div class="index-cards-container text-center">    
            <div class="index-cards grid-3">
                <div class="flip-card-container" style="--hue: 220">
                    <div class="flip-card">
                
                    <div class="card-front">
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/velg-2.jpg" alt="Brohm Lake">
                        <p class="card-text">Interieurreiniging </p>
                        </div>
                
                        <ul>
                        <li>Detail 1</li>
                        <li>Detail 2</li>
                        <li>Detail 3</li>
                        <li>Detail 4</li>
                        <li>Detail 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="card-back">
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/polijsten-4.jpg" alt="Brohm Lake">
                        </div>
                
                        <a href= "interieurreiniging.html" class="btn"><span></span>Meer informatie</a>
                
                        <div class="design-container">
                        <span class="design design--1"></span>
                        <span class="design design--2"></span>
                        <span class="design design--3"></span>
                        <span class="design design--4"></span>
                        <span class="design design--5"></span>
                        <span class="design design--6"></span>
                        <span class="design design--7"></span>
                        <span class="design design--8"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /flip-card-container -->
                
                <!-- flip-card-container -->
                <div class="flip-card-container" style="--hue: 170">
                    <div class="flip-card">
                
                    <div class="card-front">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="img-bg"></div>
                            <img src="img/polijsten-3.jpg" alt="Image 2">
                            <p class="card-text">Exterieurreiniging</p>
                        </div>
                
                        <ul>
                        <li>Detail 1</li>
                        <li>Detail 2</li>
                        <li>Detail 3</li>
                        <li>Detail 4</li>
                        <li>Detail 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="card-back">
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/matten.jpg" alt="image-2">
                        </div>
                
                        <a href= "exterieurreiniging.html" class="btn"><span></span>Meer informatie</a>
                
                        <div class="design-container">
                        <span class="design design--1"></span>
                        <span class="design design--2"></span>
                        <span class="design design--3"></span>
                        <span class="design design--4"></span>
                        <span class="design design--5"></span>
                        <span class="design design--6"></span>
                        <span class="design design--7"></span>
                        <span class="design design--8"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /flip-card-container -->
                
                <!-- flip-card-container -->
                <div class="flip-card-container" style="--hue: 350">
                    <div class="flip-card">
                
                    <div class="card-front">
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/polijsten.jpg" alt="Brohm Lake">
                        <p class="card-text">Volledige reiniging</p>
                        </div>
                
                        <ul>
                        <li>Detail 1</li>
                        <li>Detail 2</li>
                        <li>Detail 3</li>
                        <li>Detail 4</li>
                        <li>Detail 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="card-back">
                        <!-- only if the image is necessary -->
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/poetsen.jpg" alt="Brohm Lake">
                        </div>
                
                        <a href= "volledige-reiniging.html" class="btn"><span></span>Meer informatie</a>
                
                        <!-- can add svg here and remove these eight spans -->
                        <div class="design-container">
                        <span class="design design--1"></span>
                        <span class="design design--2"></span>
                        <span class="design design--3"></span>
                        <span class="design design--4"></span>
                        <span class="design design--5"></span>
                        <span class="design design--6"></span>
                        <span class="design design--7"></span>
                        <span class="design design--8"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="index-cards grid-3">
                <div class="flip-card-container" style="--hue: 220">
                    <div class="flip-card">
                
                    <div class="card-front">
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/velg-2.jpg" alt="Brohm Lake">
                        <p class="card-text">Glas- en <br> ceramische coating</p>
                        </div>
                
                        <ul>
                        <li>Detail 1</li>
                        <li>Detail 2</li>
                        <li>Detail 3</li>
                        <li>Detail 4</li>
                        <li>Detail 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="card-back">
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/polijsten-4.jpg" alt="Brohm Lake">
                        </div>
                
                        <a href= "ceramische-coating.html" class="btn"><span></span>Meer informatie</a>
                
                        <div class="design-container">
                        <span class="design design--1"></span>
                        <span class="design design--2"></span>
                        <span class="design design--3"></span>
                        <span class="design design--4"></span>
                        <span class="design design--5"></span>
                        <span class="design design--6"></span>
                        <span class="design design--7"></span>
                        <span class="design design--8"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /flip-card-container -->
                
                <!-- flip-card-container -->
                <div class="flip-card-container" style="--hue: 170">
                    <div class="flip-card">
                
                    <div class="card-front">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="img-bg"></div>
                            <img src="img/polijsten-3.jpg" alt="Image 2">
                            <p class="card-text">Velg en koplamp<br> reparatie</p>
                        </div>
                
                        <ul>
                        <li>Detail 1</li>
                        <li>Detail 2</li>
                        <li>Detail 3</li>
                        <li>Detail 4</li>
                        <li>Detail 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="card-back">
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/matten.jpg" alt="image-2">
                        </div>
                
                        <a href= "reparatie.html" class="btn"><span></span>Meer informatie</a>
                
                        <div class="design-container">
                        <span class="design design--1"></span>
                        <span class="design design--2"></span>
                        <span class="design design--3"></span>
                        <span class="design design--4"></span>
                        <span class="design design--5"></span>
                        <span class="design design--6"></span>
                        <span class="design design--7"></span>
                        <span class="design design--8"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /flip-card-container -->
                
                <!-- flip-card-container -->
                <div class="flip-card-container" style="--hue: 350">
                    <div class="flip-card">
                
                    <div class="card-front">
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/polijsten.jpg" alt="Brohm Lake">
                        <p class="card-text">Schadeherstel, uitdeuken<br> en restylen</p>
                        </div>
                
                        <ul>
                        <li>Detail 1</li>
                        <li>Detail 2</li>
                        <li>Detail 3</li>
                        <li>Detail 4</li>
                        <li>Detail 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="card-back">
                        <!-- only if the image is necessary -->
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="img-bg"></div>
                        <img src="img/poetsen.jpg" alt="Brohm Lake">
                        </div>
                
                        <a href= "schadeherstel.html" class="btn"><span></span>Meer informatie</a>
                
                        <!-- can add svg here and remove these eight spans -->
                        <div class="design-container">
                        <span class="design design--1"></span>
                        <span class="design design--2"></span>
                        <span class="design design--3"></span>
                        <span class="design design--4"></span>
                        <span class="design design--5"></span>
                        <span class="design design--6"></span>
                        <span class="design design--7"></span>
                        <span class="design design--8"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /flip-card-container -->


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

/* .flip-card-container */
.flip-card-container {
  --hue: 150;
  --primary: #9740c9;
  --white-1: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  --white-2: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  --dark: hsl(var(--hue), 25%, 10%);
  --grey: hsl(0, 0%, 50%);

  width: 310px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  /* perspective: 1000px; */
}

/* .flip-card */
.flip-card {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;

  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: .6s .1s;
}


/* hover and focus-within states */
.flip-card-container:hover .flip-card,
.flip-card-container:focus-within .flip-card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* .card-... */
.card-front,
.card-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 24px;

  background: var(--dark);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  backface-visibility: hidden;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* .card-front */
.card-front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

/* .card-back */
.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* card-content */
.card-content {
  z-index: -1;
}

/* card-content, .img-bg */
.card-content,
.img-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* img */
.flip-card img {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 24px;
  filter: blur(5px);
  
}
/* card-text */
.card-text {
  display: block;

  width: auto;
  margin-top: 12%;
  padding: 8px 22px;

  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  word-spacing: 6px;
  text-align: right;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 12px;

  color: var(--white-1);
  background: hsla(var(--hue), 25%, 10%, .5);
}

/* .img-bg */
.img-bg {
  background: hsla(var(--hue), 25%, 10%, .5);
}

.card-front .img-bg {
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.card-front .img-bg::before {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(18deg);

  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary);
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;

  transition: .1s;
}

.card-back .img-bg {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 60%);
}

/* hover state */
.flip-card-container:hover .card-front .img-bg::before {
  width: 6px;
  border-left-color: var(--primary);
  border-right-color: var(--primary);
}

/* flipcard ul */
.flip-card ul {
  padding-top: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;

  list-style: none;
  color: var(--white-1);

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* flip-card li */
.flip-card li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;

  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;

  position: relative;
}

.flip-card li:nth-child(2n) {
  color: var(--white-2);
}

.flip-card li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;

  background: currentColor;
  opacity: .2;
}

/* button */
.flip-card button {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--white-1);

  letter-spacing: 2px;

  padding: 9px 20px;
  border: 1px solid var(--grey);
  border-radius: 1000px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: .3s;

  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip-card button:hover,
.flip-card button:focus {
  color: var(--primary);
  background: hsla(var(--hue), 25%, 10%, .2);
  border-color: currentColor;
}

.flip-card button:active {
  transform: translate(2px);
}

/* smaller button */
.flip-card .btn {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
/* .design-container */
.design-container {
  --tr: 90;
  --op: .5;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  pointer-events: none;
}

/* .design */
.design {
  display: block;

  background: var(--grey);
  position: absolute;

  opacity: var(--op);
  transition: .3s;
}

.design--1,
.design--2,
.design--3,
.design--4 {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}

.design--1,
.design--2 {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--tr) - (var(--tr) * 2)) * 1%))
}

.design--1 {
  left: 20%;
}

.design--2 {
  left: 80%;
}

.design--3,
.design--4 {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--tr) + (var(--tr) - var(--tr))) * 1%))
}

.design--3 {
  left: 24%;
}

.design--4 {
  left: 76%;
}

.design--5,
.design--6,
.design--7,
.design--8 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.design--5,
.design--6 {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(calc((var(--tr) - (var(--tr) * 2)) * 1%));
}

.design--5 {
  top: 41%;
}

.design--6 {
  top: 59%;
}

.design--7,
.design--8 {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(calc((var(--tr) + (var(--tr) - var(--tr))) * 1%))
}

.design--7 {
  top: 44%;
}

.design--8 {
  top: 56%;
}

/* states */
.flip-card .btn:hover+.design-container,
.flip-card .btn:active+.design-container,
.flip-card .btn:focus+.design-container,

.flip-card button:hover+.design-container,
.flip-card button:active+.design-container,
.flip-card button:focus+.design-container {
  --tr: 20;
  --op: .7;
}
```

There is an overflow on the mobile version (I only need help for the cards, I know that the rest isn't mobile friendly as well). I want to center the cards without overflow.

Comment: you need to remove margin on `.flip-card-container` (just use `gap` instead of it) and also set width to 100% and not explicitly in `px`

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css file you have the following style declaration: `.index-cards {margin: 0 100px;}`. On mobile devices this is pushing your flip cards 100px to the right. You should change that to `.index-cards {margin: 0 auto;}` in a media query that addresses mobile screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using media-queries? You can use them to adjust the cards when they are being rendered in a mobile phone. You can check media-queries here - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, there is no need to display `.index-cards` div as a `grid` on mobile. What I suggest is that;

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .grid-3{
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    /* remove these lines
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    */
  }
  
  /* remove this margin
    .index-cards{
      margin: 0 100px;
    }
  */

  .flip-card-container{
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
  }
}
```

I took a screenshot after editing, you can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg7pE.png).

Comment: Do you know how I can make them flip on the mobile as well? If you don't have time to help I would totally understand ofcourse.

Comment: On mobile devices there are no `:hover` state, because `:hover` is for mouse devices and there are no mouse devices on mobile. But if you tap on `.flip-card-container` in a mobile device, it should work. I checked it on the mobile view of the current website and it works. Hope this helps. 

If you want help resolving the problems you have, please feel free to contact me, I'm more than happy to help. You can hit me up with a message at: https://www.linkedin.com/in/dmcshehan/